# grub key failure no boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

### Problem

Doesn't boot at all.

Keyboard inactive, no screen output. PC fans just hum on.

### Context

**Ordinary use**. The PC + setup has worked fine for months. *I wasn't fiddling*.

Boot POST test has always complained about USB setup. However, all USB ports seem(ed) to work.

### Incident - human failure

**Intention**: In grub menu - pressing arrow down key twice, to get down to Windows bootloader.

**Reality**, pressed:

1. arrow down
2. arrow left (or a combination of arrow left/arrow down)

**Result**: PC immediately bricked.

### Obstacle

No beep on boot. This PC never did that (presumably missing MB speaker).

### Setup

- custom build desktop (built by professionals, not me)
- UEFI
- grub2 dual boot
- ubuntu 22.04 on disk 1
- win11 on disk 2
- secure boot on, fast boot off
- long press on power button resets (or at least used to do)

### grub menu

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu
3. Windows bootloader (= where I wanted to go)

### Suspicion

The machine is in some kind of windowless input/output ignorant sleep mode.

### Tried

- other keyboard
- Ubuntu USB stick
- turning power on/off in multiple ways

### Hardware

- motherboard: Asus X670-P Prime (WiFi)
- processor: AMD Ryzen™ 9 7900X
- memory: Corsair DDR5-5600
- disks: Samsung 980 PRO

Comment: I don't think you bricked it. Might be that Windows tried to overwrite grub. You need to shut down (like in Restart) bevor installing Linux (if you haven't done so already).
You might have to rebuild grub (check this forum)

Comment: If UEFI, you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu often F12, but check manual. If fast boot on in UEFI Settings, you may need to fully power down & "cold" boot, not a "warm" reboot to have time to press key.

Comment: Please read the problem description before answering ;-) i. the system couldn't boot at all; ii. the system does *not* use `fast boot`. But thx anyway, for taking interest.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

**Removed a RAM stick**. Then the system was bootable. Weird state gone.
Ubuntu and Windows worked fine. And reinserting the RAM stick didn't produce a relapse ;-)

### Preventive measures

**Changed grub menu order**, placing Windows at top (default). Having Ubuntu as second option shouldn't be a problem, because I mainly use Ubuntu when working (= focused mode).

The simple way to do it would be to edit `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` (since Windows was the third option in the grub menu).
But that wouldn't have changed the *order*, it would only have changed the default preselected option.
And then I would have to hit the arrow *up* key twice to get to Ubuntu – in essence equally unsafe as the starting point (only for another OS).

Instead I changed the actual order, listening to advice at [Editing Grub2 menu entries manually in Linux Mint](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/910) (3rd comment, by bces0605), and consulting the grub2 manual: [Change script boot order by changing numbers](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId463716).
So here we go:

```
# backup existing grub.cfg
sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.bu0.before-move-windows

# list all entries (even unused)
ls -la /etc/grub.d

# move windows entry to top
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober /etc/grub.d/09_os-prober

# notify grub
sudo update-grub
```

Then I diff'ed the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` changes (using [Meld](https://github.com/GNOME/meld)) – see [grub.cfg diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt4vQ.png) – to make sure that things had worked as expected.
They had – nothing but the order had changed in `/grub.cfg`.

And new grub menu order is:

1. Windows bootloader
2. Ubuntu
3. Advanced options for Ubuntu

...which my fumbling fingers supposedly should be able to handle safely.

**Beware** that the Windows entry in your system may have another name than `30_os-prober`.